# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn.inspection'

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm following the example in [sklearn.inspection.permutation_importance](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.inspection.permutation_importance.html).

```py
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.inspection import permutation_importance
X = [[1, 9, 9],[1, 9, 9],[1, 9, 9],
     [0, 9, 9],[0, 9, 9],[0, 9, 9]]
y = [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]
clf = LogisticRegression().fit(X, y)
result = permutation_importance(clf, X, y, n_repeats=10,
                                random_state=0)
result.importances_mean
result.importances_std
```

I try to import `permutation_importance` from `sklearn.inspection`, but I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train.py", line 20, in <module>
    from sklearn.inspection import permutation_importance
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn.inspection'
```

My sklearn version is `0.20.3`

```py
import sklearn
print(sklearn.__version__)

# result: 0.20.3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[sklearn.inspection](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html#module-sklearn.inspection) is a new subpackage introduced in [Version 0.21.0](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/whats_new/v0.21.html#id14).

I need to execute `pip install --upgrade scikit-learn` to upgrade the sklearn to the newest version.